# sending 2 opposite queries from mongoose to individual tabs in one route

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a webapp where users can log in and showcase their products (studio-monitors) and add reviews to the products of other users. Each user has a dashboard with nav-tabs where they will have an access to the products that they added and to the reviews that they made. First tab is 'Users monitors' tab and the second tab is 'user review' tab.

Problem is that when I make Monitor.find({user: req.params.userId}) it will showcase all monitors added by user in the first tab, but in the review tab you will only see your reviews only for the monitors that you added. I want the review tab to show all monitors (doesn't matter if the monitor was added by another user) where the user made a review.

Problem simplified:

1. 2 queries should be made for one route. 1st one is to retrieve all monitors added by the user. 2nd is to retrieve all monitor-reviews made by user and it should also include monitors added by other users.
2. Above datas should be presented in tabs in dashboard page. It doesn't have to be tabs but the datas should be in one place.

Mongo models:

Monitors.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Monitors Schema
const MonitorSchema = new Schema({
  model: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  company: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  imgurl: {
    type: String,
  },
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  reviews: [{
    reviewBody: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    reviewDate: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    reviewUser: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'users'
    }
  }],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

mongoose.model('monitors', MonitorSchema)
```

User.js

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String
})

mongoose.model('users', UserSchema)
```

Route:
dashboard.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const async = require('async');

//Load Monitor model
require('../models/Monitors');
const Monitor = mongoose.model('monitors');

//Get Dashboard my monitors tab
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  //Check if user is logged in
  if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return next();
  }
  res.redirect('/')
}, (req, res) => {
    Monitor.find({
      user:req.user.id
    })
      .populate('user')
      .populate('reviews.reviewUser')
      .then(monitors => {
        res.render('./dashboard/dashboard', {
          monitors: monitors
        });
      });

})
```

dashboard.handlebars

```html
<div class="container content-block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <h4 class="mt-5">{{user.username}}s Dashboard</h4>

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="my-monitors-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#myMonitors" role="tab" aria-controls="myMonitors" aria-selected="true">My Monitors</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="my-reviews-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#myReviews" role="tab" aria-controls="myReviews" aria-selected="false">My Reviews</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content">

        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="myMonitors" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="my-monitors-tab">
          <div class="card-columns dashboard_monitors content-block">
            {{#each monitors}}
            <div class="card dashboard_monitors_element p-4">
              {{#if imgurl}}
              <a href="/monitors/show/{{id}}">
                <img src="{{imgurl}}" alt="{{company}} {{model}}" class="card-img-top img-fluid">
              </a> {{/if}}
              <div class="card-body">
                <a href="/monitors/show/{{id}}">
                  <h5 class="card-title mt-3">
                    {{company}} {{model}}
                  </h5>
                </a>
                <p class="card-text">
                  {{#if description}} {{truncate description 200}} {{/if}}
                  <a href="/monitors/show/{{id}}">Read more</a>
                  <hr class="my-2"> Added by
                  <a href="/monitors/user/{{user.id}}">{{user.username}}</a> on {{formatDate date 'YYYY-MM-DD'}}
                </p>

                <hr class="my-4">
                <div class="mx-auto">
                  {{#if user}} {{{edit user.id ../user.id id}}} {{/if}}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            {{else}}
            <h1>No monitors to display</h1>
            {{/each}}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="myReviews" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="my-reviews-tab">
          {{#each monitors}}
          {{#each reviews}}
          {{reviewBody}}
          {{/each}}
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```